# I have installed opencv-python using command pip, but am facing importError while executing import cv2 on aws

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, opencv

I have installed Opencv on AWS ec2-instance using **pip3 install opencv-python** but while importing cv2 it throws an error

```
import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in 
<module>
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or 
directory`
```

I have also tried to download some modules using below command to solve the issue but it also not working

```
sudo yum install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev`
sudo yum install libXtst
```